# How can I call an API when I enter the Screen and no call at pop from the next Screen in Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a question about Navigation. Let's say there are A, B, C Screens. I need to show B and I need to get data from C. And I call an API when it's B Screen. Is there any way to detect if it's from A->B or it's from pop() from C? At the moment the API is called when it's from C or A. I need to block when it's from C.

here's snippet of my code.

```
@Composable
fun ResultRoute(
    viewModel: ResultViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
   val resultData by rembember { viewModel.resultData }
   LaunchedEffect(resultData.baseId){
        if(resultData.baseId.isNullOrBlank().not()){
            viewModel.sendMessageApi(resultData.baseId)
        }
    }
    ResultScreen(resultData)
}
```

calling an API when retuning to the page is not intended. It's a bug I need to fix. How can I fix this bug?

I think this causes because `resultData` is fetched after the Route is visible.

`LaunchedEffect(Unit) {}` will be called only once but in my case, I can't use it. Otherwise, I need to get the resultData from the previous Screen and get it as param. But the resultData size is big. So, I don't want to get it as param but call from ViewModel.

Comment: It would be better if you described your initial use case rather than your partly working solution that you are trying to fix - there is probably a better way to do this. Why do you want to do this from compose in the first place? The result data comes from ViewModel and you call ViewModel method based on it - why don't you keep it all inside the ViewModel?